# rxJs forkJoin doesn't emit any values from completed not null input Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

the main thing here: the both input Observable emit values, those values aren't null and they both completed. What else I could miss?

```
this.availableHours$.subscribe(res => console.log(res)); 
this.selectedDays$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
forkJoin([this.availableHours$, this.engagedTime$]).subscribe(() => console.log('hello'));
```

I checked if they completed and emit values by separate `console.log` for each one. And result is:

```
{ availableHoursByDay: undefined } // availableHours$
{ startDate: '23.09', endDate: '25.09' } // selectedDays
{ availableHoursByDay: uundefined } // availableHours$
{ availableHoursByDay: uundefined } // availableHours$
{ availableHoursByDay: { '23.09': 1,2,3,4, '25.09': 7,4,6 } } // availableHours$
```

And 'hello' in forkJoin was not output to the console :(

So it really looks like they are completed and emit not null values. Both Observables are from store (they were received one from api call and other from routeParams and then stored to store)

What else I'm missing here?

**UPDATE.**
According to comments (guys thank you very much) I find out that the store Observables are never completed (almost never).

So now I have another question:

I need to track changes from `selectedDays$` and to take only the very last emitted value by `availableHours$` (whith not undefined properties). Only one the last. This is very important that only one

I implemented combineLatest in this way

```
   combineLatest([this.selectedDays$, availableHours$.pipe(
      filter(availableHours => !!availableHours.availableHoursByDay),
      first()
    ))
      .subscribe(([datesRange, availableHours]) => {
        this.processBookingDatesChange(datesRange, availableHours);
      });
```

but I was looking for something more elegant. What can I do here?

Comment: If `availableHours$` or `selectedDays$` are selectors from a store, then almost certainly they don't complete. You can check that with `subscribe({ next: console.log, complete: () => console.log('complete') })`

Answer (score 2):

The forkJoin emits when ALL the observables COMPLETE, not when they EMIT a value. That's a big difference.

Most probably you want the feature of combineLatest, which emits once all the observables emit.

Comment: but they all complete as you can see from console. no more values are emitted

Comment: observables of a state-management store dont complete until the store is destroyed. This only happens if the whole application is unloaded

Comment: @enno.void wow thanks a lot I didn't know that.
But how I can get only last values of both observables then? Combinelatest doesn't work for me because I have to take only one last vaue of the availableHours$ Observable

Comment: try to take availableHours$ withLatestFrom this.selectedDays$. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom

Comment: I need subscription to $selectedDays, The way you offer subscriber will be fired only if $availableHours$ emit the value. Right?

Comment: @enno.void I've updated the question providing an example of what I've implemented and what I need. Check it pls